# Reading and writing data to IPad or iPhone USB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, usb

Hi guys I've a question regarding connecting and USB to an iPad or iPod or iPhone I am planning a developing application which needs to read and write Data to USB. I bought an USB connector for iPad and iPhone. Would this even be possible without jailbreaking an iPad or iPhone?

I realy would appreciate some tips since google can't realy help me out on this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're aiming to write data via the USB to a storage device, start by visiting http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/. In your case, you may want to check out (from docs at MFI) how to write driver to push data out via the USB.